# × Error: Alchemy URL protocol must be one of http, https, ws, or wss. Recieved: undefined React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, smartcontracts, alchemy

I just clone smart contract react application in VS code and installed node modules. When i try to npm start, it gave me the error **" Error: Alchemy URL protocol must be one of http, https, ws, or wss. Recieved: undefined React.js".**

How can i solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Alchemy documentation](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/alchemy-web3),

using websockets with the `web3-alchemy` sdk requires setting up your web3 object with a websocket URL, like this:

```
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");

const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3("wss://eth-mainnet.ws.alchemyapi.io/ws/<api-key>");
```

when it is set up correctly, you should be able to make a call, for example:

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log);  // -> 7946893
```

The error you are seeing is due to an incorrect argument `undefined React.js` being passed into the alchemy web3 instantiation, basically:

```
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3( undefined React.js ); // the error is here
```

You need to figure out why there is an `undefined React.js` showing up, and once you fix that error, your app should be able to load!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure but check your `package.json` file and see the version of `react-scripts`. If it defines an older version, try updating to the latest with :

`npm uninstall react-scripts` or `yarn remove react-scripts`

and re-install using

`yarn add react-scripts` or `npm add react-scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case the problem was that in the code where you call for the json file from artifacts has to be named properly because in my case the name of the file was different so make sure that is not the case with you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).